# Investigate Chrome Physical Web not detecting urls/beacons

Tags: beacon, eddystone-url

On my desk there are two beacons set up with Eddystone URLs.

The manufacturer's app (Estimote) can see both beacons.

On the same device, Chrome's Physical Web reports "No nearby Physical Web pages found". The device is Sony Experia E2535, with Android 5.0, Chrome 52.

Physical Web app detects and displays both beacons.

What are my debugging/investigation options to establish why Physical Web doesn't display the beacons?

Comment: I have exact the same issue, have you found a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use verify.physical-web.org on the URLs that you've set in each beacon. It diagnoses most reasons why the beacons don't show up.

Comment: Side note: the page is beautiful.

Comment: Also, chrome://physical-web might give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, on Scott Jenson's advice (via github), was to update Google Play Services (in Google Play).

Comment: any solution for iOS?